# How to share dynamic content in facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, jsp, facebook-graph-api, share

In my website, user can share different songs in facebook. I want to create a common template to do that. For example, I have 2k songs in my DB. I want to share different image, title and description for each song. How to do that ??

I used this piece of code in my template file. But it is not working. Fb fetch the details from index.jsp file. It is my laning page/ home screen in my application.

http:xxxx.com/index.jsp (my home page)

http:xxxx.com/fbshare/2000( 2000 is song id and based on that I am trying to render meta tags. it is rendering properly. But facebook don't consider that)

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1664810267159599"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="http://vishnustrumpet.com"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="music.song"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="<%=session.getAttribute("URL") %>" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<%=session.getAttribute("TITLE") %>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<%=session.getAttribute("IMAGE") %>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<%=session.getAttribute("DESCRIPTION") %>" />
```

Comment: Have you set `og:url` to the correct values as well? What does the debug tool say?

Comment: yes. I set the correct value. But fb debug tool does not consider the latest value. If possible please share a piece of code